# Saying "thank you" when something is taken from you, or when you take something from someone?

Tags: formality

Often, when I am visiting some sort of community event where there is a large group of people, each person of the group may be given something to look at, or to reference to throughout the event.

For example, at a play: most of the time, visitors are given a small booklet/guide to things about the play. And, sometimes, the people running the play will collect this booklet upon your departure from the venue.

However, this is the part that confuses me: using the example, when I hand in my booklet, the collector often says:

> "Thank you"

Why are they saying "thank you"? Shouldn't I be the one saying "thank you" to them for taking the booklet from me, because then I no longer have to carry around a potential piece of trash that will most likely just get thrown away later?

---

When they say "thank you", I think it expands to:

> "Thank you for giving me your booklet."

When I say "thank you", I think it expands to:

> "Thank you for collecting my booklet from me, so I no longer have to worry about where this goes later."

Comment: Why does a waiter sometimes say *Thank you* as he leaves your table after taking your order? Partly because he's in a "service" role, and saying *Thank you* is deferential/polite. And partly because *you're helping him to do his job* - which is good for him, because if he doesn't do his job he won't get any job satisfaction (and probably won't get *paid* either! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please move that to an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etiquette rather than English.

Comment: @TimLymington I apologize. I meant to phrase my question as, "Why in English do people say [...]", but I guess it did not come correctly out of my head.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance it is simple politeness to say "Thank You" when someone hands you something.

Comment: Agreed. I said "Thank you" when the cop handed me my speeding ticket...